# MySQL Join Very Slow

Tags: mysql, performance, join

We have a problem with one of our MySQL statements.

Basically the following statement is taking 5 seconds to run. We have diagnosed 
it is down to the join of two select statement. When the select statements are 
run individually they take only 0.2 seconds but when combined with the JOIN it 
takes 5 seconds.

Is there anything you can see that we are doing wrong or can you see a better 
way?

Indexes have been added to all columns contained in the join but it does not effect the speed

```
SELECT temp_4.primaryid, temp_1.`subjectID` , temp_4.`testOccasionID` 
,`studyNumbers` ,`testDate` 

FROM (
   SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT primarys.primaryid , q_1 AS `subjectID` , q_2 AS `studyNumbers` FROM 
primarys LEFT OUTER JOIN questions_1_100 ON primarys.primaryid = 
questions_1_100.primaryid WHERE 0 = 0 AND q_1 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY primaryid) AS 
maintable_1 
GROUP BY `subjectID` ) AS temp_1 

JOIN 

(SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT primarys.primaryid , q_1 AS `subjectID` , q_4 AS `testOccasionID` , 
DATE_FORMAT(q_5, '%m/%d/%Y') AS `testDate` FROM primarys LEFT OUTER JOIN 
questions_1_100 ON primarys.primaryid = questions_1_100.primaryid WHERE 0 = 0 AND 
q_1 IS NOT NULL AND q_4 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY primaryid) AS maintable_4 
GROUP BY `subjectID` ,`testOccasionID` ) AS temp_4 

ON temp_1.`subjectID` = temp_4.`subjectID`
```

Table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE primarys 
( primaryid BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  dateinserted DATETIME,
  datemodified DATETIME,
  useridinserted BIGINT(20),
  useridmodified BIGINT(20),
  locked VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
  primaryquestionlinks TEXT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (primaryid), 
  FOREIGN KEY (useridinserted) REFERENCES users (userid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL, 
  FOREIGN KEY (useridmodified) REFERENCES users (userid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE questions_1_100
( primaryid BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  q_1 BIGINT(20),
  q_2 VARCHAR(50),
  q_3 BIGINT(20),
  q_4 BIGINT(20),
  q_5 DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (primaryid),
  FOREIGN KEY (primaryid) REFERENCES primarys (primaryid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Data for a single marching subject is as follows - the order is primaryid,q_1,q_2,q_4,q_5:

```
1    1    01001    NULL    NULL
7286 1    NULL     1       1997-12-18
7287 1    NULL     2       1998-02-25
```

The required output is:

```
7286 1    01001    1      1997-12-18
7287 1    01001    2      1998-02-25
```

Many thanks

to take this a step further... what if q_1 and q_4 were in two separate tables. such as the following table structure. The only way i can think of is to add left outer joins and several sub-queries?

```
CREATE TABLE primarys 
( primaryid BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (primaryid));

CREATE TABLE questions_1_100
( primaryid BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
q_1 BIGINT(20),
q_2 VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (primaryid));

CREATE TABLE questions_101_200
( primaryid BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
q_4 BIGINT(20),
q_5 DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (primaryid));

INSERT INTO primarys values (1);
INSERT INTO primarys values (7286);
INSERT INTO primarys values (7287);

INSERT INTO questions_1_100 VALUES (1,'1','01001');
INSERT INTO questions_1_100 VALUES (7286,'1','');
INSERT INTO questions_1_100 VALUES (7287,'1','');

INSERT INTO questions_101_200 VALUES (7286,'1','1997-12-18');
INSERT INTO questions_101_200 VALUES (7287,'2','1998-02-25');
```

Comment: Might help if we could see your database struture and some example rows.

Comment: Pl post the table structure and explain statement..

Comment: Yes we are in the process of wondering whether this is the most optimal table structure. Essentially it is a big table with no relational connections. There is a table which holds the primary keys which refer to rows in the second table. It then collects all data relating to a one object (subject) then collects all data relating to a second object (testoccasion) then combines it all together.

Comment: Please can you post the table structure and indexes so that we can suggest you necessary indexes.

Comment: CREATE TABLE primarys (
primaryid BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
dateinserted DATETIME,
datemodified DATETIME,
useridinserted BIGINT(20),
useridmodified BIGINT(20),
locked VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
primaryquestionlinks TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (primaryid),
FOREIGN KEY (useridinserted)
REFERENCES users (userid)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE SET NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (useridmodified)
REFERENCES users (userid)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE SET NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

Comment: CREATE TABLE questions_1_100(
primaryid BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
q_1 BIGINT(20),
q_2 VARCHAR(50),
q_3 BIGINT(20),
q_4 BIGINT(20),
q_5 DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (primaryid),
FOREIGN KEY (primaryid)
REFERENCES primarys (primaryid)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

Comment: I have added indexes on q_1 (pk for subject) and q_4 (pk for test occasion). In my application the test occasion is a child of subject. Thanks for the help. sorry i am new to stackoverflow and cant find a way to post as code

Comment: Its ok... :) You can use the edit link for editing the question ..

Comment: I think the last two INSERT statements should be into `questions_101_200`, not `questions_1_100`. Also, it looks as though the data has been simplified a step too far, as there is now nothing to link primary_id values 7286 and 7287 (test occasions 1 and 2) to subject 1.

Comment: Hi Mark, sorry i just noticed your response. Yes you were correct, i have now updated the original with the correct data

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

You are creating second inner query which is of no use. it would be better to remove that one.

Create these indexes table `questions_1_100` compund index (primaryid, q_1, q_4)

table `primarys` index (primaryid)

Hope this helps..

```
SELECT 
  temp_4.primaryid, 
  temp_1.`subjectID` , 
  temp_4.`testOccasionID` ,
  `studyNumbers` ,
  `testDate` 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    primarys.primaryid , 
    q_1 AS `subjectID` , 
    q_2 AS `studyNumbers` 
  FROM 
    primarys 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    questions_1_100 
  ON 
    primarys.primaryid = questions_1_100.primaryid 
  WHERE 
    q_1 IS NOT NULL 
  GROUP BY 
    primaryid, 
    subjectID) AS temp_1 
JOIN 
  (SELECT  
     primarys.primaryid , 
     q_1 AS `subjectID` , 
     q_4 AS `testOccasionID` , 
     DATE_FORMAT(q_5, '%m/%d/%Y') AS `testDate` 
  FROM 
     primarys 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     questions_1_100 
  ON 
     primarys.primaryid = questions_1_100.primaryid 
  WHERE 
     q_1 IS NOT NULL AND 
     q_4 IS NOT NULL 
  GROUP BY 
     primaryid,
     subjectID,
     testOccasionID) AS temp_4 
ON 
  temp_1.`subjectID` = temp_4.`subjectID`
```

Comment: I created the compound index and run the updated query and unfortunately it took much longer. Its about 30 seconds and still counting :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT p.primaryid , 
       q2.q_1 AS `subjectID`, 
       q4.q_4 AS `testOccasionID`, 
       q2.q_2 AS `studyNumbers`,
       DATE_FORMAT(q4.q_5, '%m/%d/%Y') AS `testDate` 
FROM primarys p
JOIN questions_1_100 q2
  ON p.primaryid = q2.primaryid
JOIN questions_1_100 q4 
  ON q2.q_1 = q4.q_1 and q4.q_4 is not null
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab7bc/8).

A simpler version, with the test occasion primaryid:

```
SELECT q4.primaryid , 
       q2.q_1 AS `subjectID`, 
       q4.q_4 AS `testOccasionID`, 
       q2.q_2 AS `studyNumbers`,
       DATE_FORMAT(q4.q_5, '%m/%d/%Y') AS `testDate` 
FROM questions_1_100 q2
JOIN questions_1_100 q4 
  ON q2.q_1 = q4.q_1 and q4.q_4 is not null
where q2.q_2 is not null
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab7bc/17).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code, this makes a great deal of sense although it is returning an empty set whereas the other code returns thousands of rows. I can't see whats different that would make it return an empty set

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your help. The first query returns an emptyset while the second does get the data extremely fast although the studynumbers column is null

Comment: @user2324001: How about now, for both queries? If there are still problems, can you add the data for a single matching subject from `questions_1_100` to your question?

Comment: The first again produces no results, the second produces more including where q_4 is null. I have attached data for a single matching subject including the required / expected output. thanks again

Comment: @user2324001: I have posted an updated version of the query that works with the data supplied. Interestingly, your original query returns no data when run against it - see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab7bc/7 .

Comment: Excellent Mark! Thank you. It all seems to be working fine. It got the original query down from 4.22 seconds to 1.64 seconds. Yes it is strange the original query didnt return any data, it was wroking fine this end..... Do you think there are any other slight tweaks that may optimise this, even slightly, such as mysql variable changes etc... once again thank you, much appreciated!!!..... or perhaps even a slightly different way of structuring the tables?

Comment: Nothing else springs to mind, unless you're willing to redesign your tables?

Comment: oh sorry i just realised it is returning the primary id from the subject row and should be the one corresponding to the testoccasion (q_4)

Comment: Actually yes i would be willing to redesign them if necessary. Id be interesting in understanding if there is better way of doing this?

Comment: Thats slightly bizarre, when i first copied and pasted it worked fine and now it isnt its returning null values for q_4

Comment: On the first point - see the updated answer. If you find the simpler query slower, then try using the old query with `SELECT p.primaryid` changed to `SELECT q4.primaryid`, or try adding an index on q_2. The last point is particularly strange, both because the query still works with the data supplide in SQLFiddle, and because the query explicitly excludes null values for q4 - `and q4.q_4 is not null`.

Comment: On redesigning tables - the q_2 information appears to relate to subjects, as does the primarys information; it would appear to make more sense to have it all on a single table (called something like subjects), with one row per subject. The q4 information appears to relate to an examination occasion; it would make more sense to have this information on a separate table (called something like examination) with one row per examination occasion, and a foreign key to subject. But then, I don't know how else you are using these tables.

Comment: Hi Mark thanks for your replies. I worked out the strange part was that my example was a simpler version of a much larger table. In fact there are multiple ids coming off the test occasion. Thank you your help has enabled me to get a grip on this and significantly speed up the query.

Comment: In regard to the table structure in fact we did used to have it in separate tables however our application is actually a very dynamic database management system. We have found the large table with essentially a key value pair has been very flexible but of course has downsides in terms of the query speed. I have heard there are 3D database structures that essentially provide this service. Have you heard of any big table / key value pairs / 3d database structures that could benefit this situation? once again, thank you, you have been a great help!

Comment: @user2324001: No, I haven't heard of any big table / key value pairs / 3d database structures that could benefit this situation, but if you find any, do let me know.

Comment: Hi Mark, sorry i just ran into one further structural issue: whereby the ids could be in 2 separate tables. I have updated the original question with the example. Personally I cant see a way of doing this without outer joins and sub-queries. Thanks for any further help